# Unable to access outlook calender from Windows Service using c#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, windows-services

I am creating a windows service which will track all the meetings present inside Outlook mails and insert into the database of meeting details but I unable to insert the meeting details it seems windows service not even recognize outlook but when I am debugging its working fine. I searched for it then I found something from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26101847/3635049) that we can't access outlook from service.Now I am bit confused that really we can't access please suggest me.

Thanks,

Prafulla.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you really cannot use Outlook or any other Office app (such as Word) from a service. The link that you [refered to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26099753/can-we-access-mail-folders-of-outlook-in-windows-service-how/26101847#26101847) lists 3 possible solutions. Which one are you confused about?